# Open port on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, port

I do not see added port 5043 from remote machine.

I added the port over Security Groups:

[image]

I'm trying to connect from remote machine but unsuccessfully.

1. Telnet connection test - port 22 - SUCCESS
   [image]
2. Telnet connection test - port 5043 - FAILED
   [image]

What I need to do to see the port from outside?

Thank you.

Comment: are you running telnet service on port 5043? And is your instance is running on public subnet with public ip?

Comment: yes i running telnet on port 5043 - see on pic above. how do I find is it on public subnet with public ip?

Comment: check whether the subnet associated with the instance has internet gateway or not.

Comment: I'm afraid @NaveenKerati seems to be guessing, rather than troubleshooting. `Connection refused` has a very specific meaning and unreachable is not one of them.  The machine *is accessible* but no service is bound to port 5043 on an outward facing IP address... but if it seems to work locally, this suggests that perhaps it is bound only to 127.0.0.1, not 0.0.0.0.  Show `netstat -a -n | grep 5043` in the machine where the service is running, please.

Comment: @Michael: "netstat -a -n | grep 5043" - nothing is displayed

Comment: When run on the server?  Then in thst case, you don't have a service listening on port 5043. `Connection refused` would be the expected error.

Comment: I have a solution. My service has been set to http://localhost:5043. I set up http://0.0.0.0:5043 and everythings works fine. Thank you all mainly to Michael.

Answer (score 0):

you can try nmap to check what ports are open and which services are running on the ports in remote machine.

```
nmap -sT <Instance Public IP-address>
```

Comment: Result nmap -sT :

Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.08 seconds

Comment: Result nmap -Pn:
Host is up (0.062s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
9200/tcp closed wap-wsp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.29 seconds

Comment: It looks like your instance is not reachable.